# Trying to pass variables from two table cells to a PHP file but $_GET() truncates the text string

Tags: php, html

I have created a table from my MySQL Table.
Each row has five columns and the fifth column contains a hyperlink to a new php file. The new php file requires the variables contained in columns 3 and 4.
My code for populating the table cells is as follows;

```
<form method="GET" action="Web_Match_Sheet.php">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="960">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="935" >
         <tr>
            <th style="width: 187px;">Date</th>
            <th style="width: 187px;">First Tee Time</th>
            <th style="width: 187px;">Opponents</th>
            <th style="width: 187px;">Venue</th>
            <th style="width: 187px;"></th> 
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:960px; height:600px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="935" >
           <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 187px;"><?php echo date('jS F, Y', strtotime($row[0]));?></td>
                <td style="width: 187px;">@&nbsp;<?php echo substr($row[1],0,5);?></td>
                <td style="width: 187px;"><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
                <td style="width: 187px;"><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
                <td style="width: 187px;"><a href="edit.php?Opponents=<?php echo $row[2];?> & Venue=<?php echo $row[3];?>">Team Sheet/Results</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The line

```
<td style="width: 187px;"><a href="edit.php?Opponents=<?php echo $row[2];?> & Venue=<?php echo $row[3];?>">Team Sheet/Results</a></td>
```

call the php file edit.php and passes two variables "Opponents" and "Venue".

The edit.php file is as follows;

```
<?php
session_start();
$uOpponentName = $_GET['Opponents'];
$_SESSION["Opponents"] = $uOpponentName;
$uVenue = $_GET['Venue'];
$_SESSION["Venue"] = $uVenue;
header('Location: Web_match_Sheet.php');
?>
```

All works fine, apart from the fact that $_GET() truncates the Opponents variable.
i.e. Bristol City becomes Bristol
I have tried a number of changes but all failed.
Can anyone point me to a solution.
Bit of a novice at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string needs some work. There should be no spaces that aren't part of a value, and any spaces in a value should be properly encoded. (They should appear in the URL as `+`.)

PHP has a built-in function [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) that can help you produce a proper query string like this.

```
$query = http_build_query(['Opponents' => $row[2], 'Venue' => $row[3]]);
```

Then you can append that query string to your URL.

```
<a href="edit.php?<?= $query ?>">test<a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a `urlencode()` on the value before putting it in the link address.

`urlencode($row[2]);` (Or whichever is causing the issue.)